# Using the Socket.IO framework with native WebSocket clients

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am looking to leverage my existing (and quite simple) NodeJS+SocketIO server application with a new Android based client. This is not using the WebKit browser, but a native WebSocket client within the Android SDK.

I have found the library "Weberknecht" and loaded it into my Android project, and when I attempt a connection to the WebSocket URL I see a `"WARN - client not handshaken client should reconnect"` message in my NodeJS trace.

Presumably the SocketIO framework does some extra work pre-WebSocket and that is why I am having issues. Has anyone else done this kind of "cross-library" work against SocketIO, and if so could you offer any assistance please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a [Java client](https://github.com/benkay/java-socket.io.client) for Socket.IO, you can look at the different port at the [wiki page](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki). Also, there is a description of the socket.IO [protocol](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec) on the wiki page.

It seems like the first thing that Java port does when it connects is that it sends a "1::(path)" connect message. Are you sending the connect message?

Comment: Agreed. I found this a day or so ago. I did have to do some recompiling work but I now have a simple JAR library which works in Android. I will be publishing this, with consent from the authors, ASAP.

Comment: @richbayliss Have you published the library somewhere?

Comment: @SagarHatekar unfortunately not yet. I have been tied up with other things. I will try and find some time to do this and I will update this thread with details.

Comment: @richbayliss Okay, waiting to check it out. What license do you plan to publish it with?

Comment: Hey Rich, I'd be interested in your lib that works on android, is it up yet?

Comment: @richbayliss did you have a chance to publish the library.  It sounds wondeful.  I would love to be able to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer, then checkout out https://github.com/koush/android-websockets, which got released recently. It has full support for socket.io server running in node.js